# Amazon AWS Security Group - Allow Microsoft Azure Web App IP Address

Tags: sql, azure, amazon-web-services, ip-address, static-ip-address

This is the first time I've published a web app on Azure.  I have a SQL Server database on Amazon AWS that I'm connecting to.  I need to set the security group to allow the Azure Web App to connect.  How do I get the IP address of the Azure web app?
From what I understand about Azure, the web apps have a rotating IP address because they're on shared servers.  What can I tell the security group to allow?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [Azure Outbound Address](http://ruslany.net/2015/06/how-to-find-out-outbound-ip-addresses-used-by-azure-web-app/)

There can be only 4 IPs your web app can have. Add 4 rules to your SG, one for each IP. It is much safer than allowing a larger CIDR block.

Comment: Where do I get those four IPs?

Comment: Check the link mentioned in my answer or Azure Resource Explorer: https://resources.azure.com

Comment: That's awesome.  Thanks for the link.  I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

As MS updated their portal, So it would look like the attached screen shot.

[image]